# Suppose U and V are both 4-dim. subspaces of C^(6). Prove there exist 2 vectors in U ∩ V s.t. these vectors are not a scalar multiple of the other.

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to go about proving this question. I was thinking maybe I could state that the dimension of the intersection of U and V is smaller than the dimension of C^6. Then go about talking about basis and spanning list and reach the conclusion that there are linearly independent vectors in U and V thus they are not scalar multiples of the other.

Comment: You're on the right track with dimensions though your reasoning goes a little astray from there. What's the minimum dimension of $U\cap V$? Do you see how this does what you need?

Comment: I got that the minimum dimension of U and V is 2. Is that correct? Would I use this to state that the length of the basis of the vector space is 2? Where would I go from here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrase "length of the basis" but instead say something like "the basis has two elements." We know that $U\cap V$ has dimension greater than or equal to 2 so its basis has at least two vectors. What do you know about basis vectors?

Comment: Basis consists of vectors in V that is linearly independent and spans V. So since we know there are at least two basis vectors in U and V, they are linearly independent, and since they are linearly independent, they can't be multiples of the other. Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: Yep it is!$\,\,\,$

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm going to type up a quick answer to this because if it doesn't have an answer, it'll keep getting bumped by Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum dimension of $U\cap V$, as you noted, is $2$, which in turn says that $U\cap V$ has a basis that consists of *at least* $2$ elements. Since basis vectors are linearly independent, you have your result.